# Django : Type Error 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, django, typeerror, nonetype

im making a product checkout page and im trying to access my cart items from the following util.py file. I have seen that lot of sites saying that the 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable error, means that i attempted to index an object that doesn't have that functionality. But i cant figure out what is wrong. The error occurs in the `cartData` function

views.py

```
from .utils import cartData

def checkout(request):

    #call method from utils.py
    data =cartData(request)
    cartItems = data['cartItems'] 
    order = data['order']
    items = data['items']

    context = {
        'items': items,
        'order': order,
        'cartItems': cartItems
    }
    return render(request, 'store/checkout.html', context)
```

utils.py

```
def cookieCart(request):
    try:
        cart = json.loads(request.COOKIES['cart'])

    except:
        cart = {}

    print('Cart', cart)
    items = []
    order = {'get_cart_total': 0, 'get_cart_items': 0, 'shipping': False}
    cartItems = order['get_cart_items']

    for i in cart:
        # check if product exists
        try:
            cartItems += cart[i]['quantity']

            product = Product.objects.get(id=i)
            total = (product.price * cart[i]['quantity'])

            order['get_cart_total'] += total
            order['get_cart_items'] += cart[i]['quantity']

            item = {
                'product': {
                    'id': product.id,
                    'name': product.name,
                    'price': product.price,
                    'imageURL': product.imageURL,
                },
                'quantity': cart[i]['quantity'],
                'get_total': total
            }
            items.append(item)
           

            if product.digital == False:
                order['shipping'] = True
        except:
            pass
        return{'cartItems': cartItems, 'order': order, 'items': items}


def cartData(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
            customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartItems = order.get_cart_items
    else:
        # call method from utils.py
        cookieData = cookieCart(request)
        cartItems = cookieData['cartItems'] //the'NoneType' object is not subscriptable error occurs here
        order = cookieData['order']
        items = cookieData['items']
    return {'cartItems': cartItems, 'order': order, 'items': items}
```

Comment: Would also like to add the line number where you are getting the error?

Comment: I guess some exception is occured inside `try/except` but you are covering it and have `pass` as a result your function will return `None` by default. So what I suggest, remove that `try/except` so you will see what is failing inside it.

Comment: What do you want to get from this statement?  customer = request.user.customer

Comment: I see a problem in your cookieCart function because if the for loop not invoked because the cart variable is empty dict you are returning None that is why you are receiving this error

Comment: @jaswanth thank you very much, it was just another silly error